# Can I set an image as background for the bottom of a Layout

Tags: android, layout

- I'd like to have the image set as background to the bottom 30% of the layout.

At the moment I have it as a separate image view which will be placed within the layout aligned to the bottom and this works, I'm aware of options like having the imageview within the layout with weight also.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/gb"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

I'm just wondering if it'd be possible to **set it as the background for the parent layout(aligning it to the bottom 30%,not the entire layout)**,Avoiding me the headache of the Imageview appearing above the soft keyboard overlapping other components in the layout whenever it opens and such.Let me not discuss about all that. As of now I'd just like to know whether what I asked above is possible.

*I'm sorry if I was not able to convey what I need properly,
I'm asking if I can set it as background for the layout without creating a separate image view.More like aligning the background of the layout to the bottom 30%.*

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` inside your `RelativeLayout` and set `ImageView` weight to `0.3`. Set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to `LinearLayout` to make it appear on bottom.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gb"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not able to convey what I need properly, I'm asking if I can set it as background for the layout without creating a separate image view.More like aligning the background of the layout to the bottom 30%.

Comment: No issue. Please post your complete layout file so that we can help you

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that using weight or using a relative layout and aligning the image to the parent bottom is a more ideal approach than what I asked. Anyway thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/gb" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not able to convey what I need properly, I'm asking if I can set it as background for the layout without creating a separate image view.More like aligning the background of the layout to the bottom 30%.

Comment: Its quite complex but possible, for do that you have to create a custom view from java.

Comment: I guess you're right its complex and not the ideal way to do it.Thanks.